# GitHub App - generate permanent installation access token

Tags: authentication, github, github-api

Is there way to let the user who installs a GitHub App generate a permanent installation access token which can be used by the app to authenticate and perform actions as that app?

I am wanting to create a simple GitHub App that will run on a CI server and comment on PRs with data from one of the tests.

As this app is being run by the user on their CI server there is no place to store the private key for the GitHub App that would usually be used to generate the access token as described [here](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-github-apps/about-authentication-options-for-github-apps).

Ideally if the user could generate a permanent installation access token for the app they could securely provide that key to the app when it runs on the CI server so the app can communicate with the GitHub API and authenticate as the app.

I realize that the user could provide a user access token and the app could authenticate that way - but when the app comments it needs to show up as originating from the app, not the user (and I don't believe that would happen if the app authenticates with a user access token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing "GitHub Apps" with the more generic idea of tools that access the GitHub API. The Apps system a specific way to build hosted services for GitHub that has its own authentication model. Users can't run an App themselves as it is only designed around hosted/SaaS tooling. For things that someone would run themselves, you would need the end user to create a new user account on GitHub for the bot and then authenticate as it (either OAuth or personal access token, doesn't matter).

Comment: Yeah - I understand that GitHub Apps _shouldn't_ be run directly by the user. I'm just trying to avoid having to force a user to create a new GitHub account just to act as the bot. They might already have a second account acting as another bot (and I believe the TOS technically only allow 1 bot account/real person).

Comment: Are you making an App or something else that happens to use the API?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in the interest of having the correct info here...

@osowskit's answer is correct in terms of mentioning you need to use JWT but not in terms of that has to be done using webhooks. There are indeed advantages of using Apps for access control - the GitHub App can be given specific access for only some repos. Now at least some CI systems (well at least Jenkins) support GitHub App access natively for some uses.

The basic flaw in the original request was the request of a permanent PAT associated with the App. This is not how they work. Instead you generate a Private Key for the App and it is this that should be stored in the CI secrets system. Now you do indeed need some sort of PAT to actually do the action - here to add the PR comment - it is just that you don't have a permanent one. Instead you generate temporary PATs each time you need to run - IIRC these PATs last for about an hour, so are useful for most single jobs but are to be generated each time and not stored as such.

Once you get the code, it is no big deal using the jwt tokens - it just involves a couple of extra REST calls.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there way to let the user who installs a GitHub App generate a permanent installation access token which can be used by the app to authenticate and perform actions as that app?

Maybe but it shouldn't be necessary. A GitHub App will only perform actions on data a user grants it access to. Any data modified on GitHub by the App will appear as an action 'performed' by the App.

> Ideally if the user could generate a permanent installation access token for the app they could securely provide that key to the app when it runs on the CI server so the app can communicate with the GitHub API and authenticate as the app.

This shouldn't be necessary based on the information you've provided. Users grant access to a GitHub App to access specific resources and listen for specific events; a GitHub App needs a installation ID (or multiple installation IDs) to interact with GitHub data.

The good news is that for the CI workflow you outlined, GitHub would send the installation ID in the webhook payload - likely a `push` event.

> I realize that the user could provide a user access token and the app could authenticate that way - but when the app comments it needs to show up as originating from the app, not the user (and I don't believe that would happen if the app authenticates with a user access token).

Generating a personal access token (PAT) isn't required and GitHub Apps were created to avoid creating service accounts or adding credentials to your CI environment.

1. Author your GitHub App to listen for webhook events.
2. On receiving an event, parse the payload for the `installation id`
3. Generate an `installation access token` by [authenticating as an application](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-github-apps/about-authentication-options-for-github-apps/#authenticating-as-an-installation) after creating a JWT.
4. Use the `installation access token` generated above to modify data. Note that this token expires in an hour.
5. Profit!

Comment: Thanks but I think you might be misunderstanding my use case. My GitHub App is not being invoked by a webhook. It is running as part of a CI test pipeline. Step 3 isn't possible as there is no place to store the private key without users having access to it. The app is being run by the end user. As @coderanger mentioned it may not be possible to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: You could run this app as an independent service - not on their CI system, which would allow the intended behavior. If that's not desired, then an OAuth App is likely a better fit.

Comment: I understand - but that's adding a lot of overhead for a simple app that just needs to comment on PRs. OAuth App brings back the issue of commenting as the user (which I don't want - I want it to comment as the App).